# Recursion to find the amount of same elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I was having some difficulties when trying to perform a search on array elements using recursion. The expected output should be like this:

```
Enter array size: 10
Enter 10 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9
Enter the target number: 5
rCountArray() = 2
```

And the recursion part of my code:

```
int rCountArray(int array[], int n, int a)
{
    int found = 0;
    if (n < 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(array[n] == a){
        ++found;
        return found;
    }
    rCountArray(array, n + 1, a);
}
```

The problem now is no matter how many repeated elements inside the array, it always give me the value 1.

I was thinking is it because everytime the recursion occurs, if the array element is same as target, I am setting the value for `found` variable to 0 and increment by 1 and that's why the value does not add up and instead, returning me with 1 only?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

*Edited*

```
int main()
{
    int array[SIZE];
    int index, count, target, size;

    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", size);
    for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
        scanf("%d", &array[index]);
    printf("Enter the target: ");
    scanf("%d", &target);
    count = rCountArray(array, size, target);
    printf("rCountArray() = %d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that `size <= SIZE` before calling `rCountArray()` else you will have **serious** problems inside this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your original code:

- The first `if` should test for `< 0` because you want it to execute the next test when the array index becomes **0**.
- It shouldn't `return -1`, ever! When the function fails it must return **0**.
- Do not return after `found` is incremented.
- When `rCountArray()` is called recursivelly, `n + 1` should be `n - 1` to decrement the index of the array.
- The actual return instruction should be: `found + rCountArray()`

.

```
int rCountArray(int array[], int n, int a)
{
    int found = 0;
    if (n < 0) 
        return 0;

    if (array[n] == a)
        ++found;

    return (found + rCountArray(array, n - 1, a));
}
```

Comment: `n` is the size of the array and `a` is the number being searched for. Searching for a number that doesn't exist in the array will return **zero**.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! I see my mistakes there :) Thanks for pointing them out with detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be

`return rCountArray(array, n + 1, a);`

What you have above is undefined behavior, because you are falling off the end of a non-void function without returning.

Additionally, in the case `array[n] == a`, you should return `1 + rCountArray(array, n + 1, a);`. Just because you found a match, doesn't mean you should stop searching, you want to find all the matches!

Finally, there needs to be some stopping condition. For instance, you could pass the size of the array also, and stop when you get there. Or, `n` could start at the size of the array, and you could decrement it instead of incrementing it.

How exactly are you calling this function?

Also as a final bit of advice, if it were me I would not use recursion for this, I would just use a for loop, because its simpler and faster.

Comment: I thought I am returning the found variable? That last line is basically just a recursion to loop thru the array elements. Let me edit the calling part. Actually the use of recursion is part of the instruction, I personally preferred for loop also :)